# Алгоритм решения задачи

Tags: алгоритм

Дана таблица произвольной размерности, где 
**A,B,C..., W1, W2, W3... - известны**  и **A+B+C+... = W1+W2+W3+...**.
Например,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где С=С1+С2+С3 и т.д, W2=B2+C2+D2 и т.д

Требуется рассчитать значение коэффициентов в таблице *A1,A2..,B1,B2.., C1,C2..* .
ГУ: в каждой строке или столбце есть как минимум один коэффициент. Коэффициенты - рациональные положительные.

В каком направлении рыть, алгоритм, метод...?

Comment: решение системы линейных уравнений?

Comment: Да, это они есть) Руками то я её решаю

Comment: В этом примере 7 переменных и 7 уравнений. Но как это сделать в случае когда, таблица полностью заполнена?

Comment: Если таблица полностью заполнена, то она может иметь бесконечное кол-во решений. Только ограничения на то, что они положительные, немного ограничивает возможные варианты.

Comment: мне нужно любое подходящее решение... сейчас смотрю метод ортогонализации

Comment: Обычная СЛАУ. Sum(Ai)=A; Sum(Bi)=B;...;Sum(xi)=x;Sum(x1)=W1;Sum(x2)=W2;...Sum(xN)=WN. И решается соответствующим образом.